# Bash: CP will consider file with extension as duplicate as file without it

Tags: bash, cp

I'm running

```
cp -dR "${SOURCE_DIR}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
```

And there's one place with a file *something* and *something.exe*. 
CP is failing because it considers both of them the same file. Can this be forced somehow?

Comment: Well, are you using `Cygwin`?

Comment: Hmm I'm using Git Bash (mintty) under Windows 10.

Comment: I can reproduce with the following code : `mkdir source target; touch source/file{,.exe}; cp -R source target`. The `file.exe` is copied, then when `cp` tries to copy the `file` it fails because it finds `file` already exists in the target dir (when it's actually `file.exe`). The problem doesn't happen without `-R`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `find`-based alternative :

```
find source/ -type d -exec mkdir target/{} \; -o -type f -exec cp -d {} target/{} \;
```

It recurses over the content of the `source/` directory, using `mkdir` to create directories it encounters in the target directory and `cp` to copy the files one by one.

I expect this will be quite slower than your original `cp -R` would have been. If you've got the `rsync` binary available (not by default with `git bash` AFAIK) you should give it a try, it might not have the same unfortunate interaction with `git bash` and its `.exe` simplification that you found in `cp -R` and should be faster than my solution.